# Paladin and truffle won't spawn

Tags: terraria

I have the perfect house for my truffle in a mushroom biome and it has been saying "Porcini would like to settle Down" for the past 3 months. Any advice for how to get him to spawn quicker? On the other hand my Paladins won't spawn either. I go in the dungeon almost every time I play terraria to try to get the Paladins shield but I can't get it because he won't spawn. Any advice to help me?

Comment: That settle down messgae seems to say your truffle (or some NPC with the name Porcini) has spawned, but doesn't have a valid house available.

Comment: How long do you spend in the dungeon? The paladin is a rare spawn.

Answer (score 3):

The requirements for Truffle to spawn, as stated on [this wikia page](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Truffle):

> The Truffle is a hard mode NPC and will only show up once you have constructed a house in an above-ground mushroom biome with Mushroom Grass Seeds, or by using the Clentaminator in a Jungle.

Also mentioned on this page, is that to better your chances for him to appear, you might want to build his house completely out of glowing mushroom materials.

The requirements for the Paladin to spawn as stated on [this wikia page](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Paladin):

> The Paladin is a miniboss that spawns in the Hard Mode Dungeon after Plantera has been defeated.

If all those requirements are met, they should have no problems spawning in your world. The only thing that may prevent them from spawning is by playing in a world generated before the version 1.2 patch.

Comment: I'll add one important thing about the paladin, he only spawns in front of one of the three types of dungeon wall, which proves your point of a world generated before the 1.2 version.
A dungeon can also be generated without one type of wall (happened to me once in a small world, couldn't have the sniper spawning)

Answer (score 0):

The truffle is more likely to spawn when there are no villagers trying to settle down and there are no other villagers in that biome. As for the paladin, the background has to be the brick background, not the other 2 variants. This site shows the variants and what spawn there. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Brick_Wall. The colour doesn't matter. Try using battle potions and water candles as well. You also might have to update the game a bit.